# OAuth1 with requests_oauthlib produces URL encoding error

Tags: python, oauth, urlencode

I am using the requests_oauthlib module for OAuth authentication.
Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the OAuth1 workflow acoording to step one in this tutorial: http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth1_workflow.html
If I try to obtain a fetch response it throws me the followin error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neumannr/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 195, in fetch_request_token
    token = self._fetch_token(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 264, in _fetch_token
    token = dict(urldecode(self.post(url).text))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/common.py", line 135, in urldecode
    raise ValueError('Not a valid urlencoded string.')
ValueError: Not a valid urlencoded string.
```

My testing code looks as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


# Using OAuth1Session
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

# Using OAuth1 auth helper
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

client_key = 'a'
client_secret = 'b'
request_token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'


# Using OAuth1Session
oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key, client_secret=client_secret)
fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
```

Since the URL is not being URL encoded within the tutorial either, I do not understand why this happens. If I try to URL encode the URL like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


# Using OAuth1Session
import urllib
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

# Using OAuth1 auth helper
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

client_key = 'a'
client_secret = 'b'
request_token_url = urllib.quote('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token')


# Using OAuth1Session
oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key, client_secret=client_secret)
fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
```

I get a missing schema error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neumannr/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 195, in fetch_request_token
    token = self._fetch_token(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 264, in _fetch_token
    token = dict(urldecode(self.post(url).text))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 377, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 324, in request
    prep = req.prepare()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 222, in prepare
    p.prepare_url(self.url, self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 291, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema("Invalid URL %r: No schema supplied" % url)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'https%3A//api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token': No schema supplied
```

How do I use oauthlib_requests anyway?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

The error can be a result of a failed attempt to decode the response. For more details, please  see [OAuthlib issue 124](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/issues/124).